# Workflow to resize and crop an image weighted on coordinate

Tags: math, image-processing, image-manipulation, face-detection

I'm working on a resize and crop workflow to allow images to be resized and then cropped to a specific size. Normally one resize the smallest dimension to fit the destination size, and then crop to get eg. a square.

However, in this case, I have some additional face-detection data: face_x, face_y and face_width and face_height. The X and Y coordinates of the face is top-left point in the original picture of where the face starts.

I want the cropped area to be centered at the face instead of in the center of the image.

Any smart minds out there who can help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The center of the face is

```
(face_x + face_width/2, face_y+face_height/2).
```

If you want the image to be (w, h) at the end, then the upper left is

```
(face_x + (face_width - w)/2, face_y + (face_height - h)/2)
```